# exporting enum without module flag

Tags: enums, typescript

I have the following typescript code:

```
// file1.ts
export enum Status {
    Active = 1,
    NotActive = 0
}
```

other parts I have

```
// file2
import {Status} from "./file1";
...
```

When I compile the code I get this message:

```
error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided. 
Consider setting the 'module' compiler option in a 'tsconfig.json' file.
```

My tsconfig file, just in case:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "javascript/app.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": false
    },
    "files": [
        "app.ts"
    ]
}
```

Now I don't want to export any modules, rather I want to produce a self contained file which has all source code, so I can just include on file on the browser.

How can rewrite/reformulate the enum to avoid this compile message and produce a self contained file ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> Now I don't want to export any modules, rather I want to produce a self contained file which has all source code, so I can just include on file on the browser.

If this is the case, do the following:

1. Remove the `export` modifier from `file1.ts`
2. Remove the entire `import` declaration from `file2.ts`
3. Add `/// <reference path="file1.ts" />` to the top of `file2.ts`

Now `app.js` will be the concatenated output of `file1.ts` + `file2.ts`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, one question why when I export class I don't need --module but when I export enum I need one ?

Comment: They behave the same. I'm guessing you had your class inside a `namespace` or `module`, where `export` means something different

Answer (score 0):

I see in your case you don't seem to have a module. If you are struggling to include an enum in a module that is declared in another file, such as a component it can be done like so:

**Declare your enum:**
In your component after your *imports* and before your *@Component* declaration, declare your enum. Do not make your enum a *const*.

```
export enum MyEnum { DEFAULT = 'default', WORKING = 'working', COMPLETE = 'complete' }
```

This make your enum accessible to your component class without having a cirular reference from declaring it in your module file.

**Import your enum:**
In your module *imports*, import your enum and give it an alias.

```
import { MyComponent, MyEnum as _myEnum } from "./my-component.component";
```

**Re-declare your enum:**
In your module after your *imports* and before your *@NgModule*, export and declare your enum as a *const*.

```
export const MyEnum = _myEnum;
```

Now when you import your module, MyEnum will be available to reference.

If you need to access the enum from the template then give the enum a local type that is part of the component class. Inside your component class declare:

```
private myEnum = MyEnum;//myEnum is accessible in the template.
```